# Is there a checkbox in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, checkbox

I'm looking for a checkbox component in Swift. UISwitch seems not so handy because there I found no way to define a label for it.
Very good I find the component the iPhone used when turning on and off the personal hotspot. But I do not know what it is?

Comment: It's a custom `UITableViewCell`, with a `UISwitch`.

Comment: It is related to the iOS, not the Swift programming language itself.

Comment: Why not use a UIButton with check image?

Answer (score 1):

There's no native radio button in iOS. As you can see in iOS, Apple uses `UISwitch` as mention by Sweeper.

Now if you aim to achieve something like this, then you can make your own control or use some 3rd party open source libraries like `VKCheckBox`. https://github.com/vladislav-k/VKCheckbox

I've been using this custom control and you can integrate it by either `Cocoapods` or by merely importing its one and only class to your project.

[image]

Comment: Using UITableViewCell and UISwitch sounds interesting. Can you give a small example of how I have to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no checkbox control available on iOS but i was achieve it using CZPicker view, it's allows to select single and multiple options from list

Please check this URL : https://github.com/chenzeyu/CZPicker

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have cerated checkbox with uibutton subclass -- using image and title both and adjsuting title and image with title offset and image offset.

1. Put a property isSelected -- On DidSet I change the image of button for select/unselect.
   2.On click of button I toggle the property isSelected
2. On click button I triger a delegate call back for get buttons selected/unselect state in view controller.

Hope It will help.

Comment: First of all - thanks for your good idea. The problem is that the app should be accessible for screenreader users and that's why I can't use an UIButton with image or custom style because the screenreader give no feecback in this case.